# Number of sing-copy genes identified by orthofinder is far less than BUSCO assessment?

Tags: orthologues, busco, orthofinder

Dear Orthofinder users and BUSCO users,

Recently, I have assessed 30 genome annotataions `using BUSCO with lineage` dataset `ascomycota_odb10`, I got 1100+ complete and single-copy genes. But the `orthofinder`  only identified 300+ single-copy genes. Aneone else have encountered this similar problem?

Thanks,

Yanpeng

Comment: I know what caused the difference. BUSCO uses more strict criterion to determine single-copy genes but manly of the result genes are identified as multicopy genes by OrthoFinder using less strict parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the exact commands you used. However, Orthofinder identifies/defines single-copy orthologues as those genes present in a single copy in all species being compared in the analysis. If a BUSCO orthologue is present in more than one copy in one of the species being compared (could be multi-copy, could be fragmented etc.), then it won't be recovered as single copy by Orthofinder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I run `OrthoFinder` with default parameters. The BUSCO identified 1000+ complete single-copy genes but only 387 identified by OrthoFinder. I am trying to confirm whether BUSCO single-copy genes are true single-copy.